# Building PJSIP using g++ compiler

Tags: c++, g++, debian, pjsip

I want to compile PJSIP library using g++ compiler in a Debian OS.Could any one help me with the appropriate  steps to do the same?

Comment: http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Autoconf `./configure && make dep && make && make install`

Answer (score 1):

According to [INSTALL.txt](http://svn.pjsip.org/repos/pjproject/branches/1.x/INSTALL.txt) you should:

```
-= COMPILING =-

With Makefile:
 - on top level dir (e.g. ~/pjproject)
 - ./configure && make dep && make clean && make
```

Comment: Thank You for the answer. But this would compile using the gcc command  and not g++ right? I basically modified pjsua_app.c code into  c++ program to test a few things.I am a beginner into Linux and also using gcc compiler. Is it possible that I can use the same steps to get it working?

Comment: Yes, by default gcc will be used. To use g++ set env variable `CXX=g++` before running configure. This is described in [this](http://svn.pjsip.org/repos/pjproject/branches/1.x/aconfigure) configure file.